# Running python script with shell_exec() in php script results in permission denied error

Tags: python, php, permissions, permission-denied, shell-exec

I am connected to my OracleLinux server via an SSH connection. The server is running a working apache webserver and also php. Python3 is also installed.

Now I am currently trying to run a php script via a JavaScript AJAX request to in turn run a Python script with it.

Directory structure:

```
/var/www/website/webwatcher
--index.html
--js/
-----script.js (run PHP script from here with AJAX request)
--php/
-----getWebsiteElementValue.php (run webscraper.py from here)
--python/
-----webscraper.py
```

`script.js`:

```
window.onload = () => {
    
    getWebsiteElementValue((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}

function getWebsiteElementValue(success) {
    let ajax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    let ajaxURL = '/webwatcher/php/getWebsiteElementValue.php';
    ajax.open('post', ajaxURL);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (ajax.readyState > 3 && ajax.status == 200) {
            success(ajax.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajax.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    ajax.send();
}
```

`getWebsiteElementValue.php`:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /var/www/website/webwatcher/python/webscraper.py 2>&1');
    echo $output;
?>
```

`webscraper.py`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from sys import argv
import ssl

url = 'https://buyzero.de/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b-8gb?variant=31817426698342';
cssSelector = 'div.product-form__info-list > div:nth-child(2) > div > span';

context = ssl._create_unverified_context();
page = urlopen(url, context=context);
html = page.read().decode("utf-8");
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser");

elementText = soup.select(cssSelector)[0].text;
print(elementText);
```

When I run the python script via the terminal, it returns the desired output without error.
However, when the same happens via the shell_exec() php command I get the following error messages (shortened) in the console of the website:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` and
`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 13] Permission denied>`

The `/var/www` folders both have the following permissions `drwxr-xr-x.` and belong to `root:root`.
The directory structure of `website/` up to the file `webscraper.py` (also all subfolders and files in it) belongs to `apache:apache` and has the permissions `drwxrwxr-x.` and `-rwxrwxr-x.` respectively.

Where is the error now?

Comment: have you check your `/usr/bin/python3` permission? can user `apache` have permission to run `python3`

Comment: I just checked this out. The paths `/usr/bin/python3` linking to `/etc/alternatives/python3` linking to `/usr/bin/python3.6` linking to `/usr/libexec/platform-python3.6` all have `lrwxrwx.` or `-rwxrwx.` permissions and belong to `root:root`. Is the owner/group `root:root` perhaps the problem? Actually, the last triplet with `rwx` should allow other users (here `apache`) to execute the python3 command or am I wrong?

Comment: it is seem you missing 3 more letter in the permission. you can try using `python3` under `apache` privilege for confirmation. You can use `sudo su apache` to execute thing with `apache` privilege

Comment: Beacause python command is executed (you got the error from the python runtime), maybe there is some issue with permissions to python libraries? It sould be for example Selinux policy which blocks connection (# setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on). Check grep python /var/log/audit/audit.log for possible errors.

Comment: @MaciejWrobel The command `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on` command was the solution! Now it's working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MaciejWrobel's comment brought me to the solution of the problem.

Because the `httpd_can_network_connect` boolean of the Linux system is set to `off` by default, it seems to prevent access to various Python modules in a Python script and ends up in the above error. Running the command `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on` in the terminal **fixed my problem**.